# Angular - Validation on button click then next function

Tags: html, angularjs

New to Angular so apologies if this question has been asked before.

I've got field validation working well with `ng-messages` (great tutorial [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html) if anyones interested).

However what I've read/learnt so far does validation whenever fields are touched.

```
<div ng-messages="{ required: !main.o1ToAdd || !main.o2ToAdd }"
            ng-if="myForm.o1.$touched || myForm.o2.$touched">
    <span ng-message="required">you need to specify at least 2</span>
</div>
```

and on the inputs

```
<input name="o1" ng-model="main.o1ToAdd" type="text" placeholder="Yes" required
   ng-class="{ 'invalidInputField': myForm.o1.$touched && myForm.o1.$invalid }"/>
```

However I dont really want an error to appear if a user clicks on a field.

Instead I have a post button - so if thats click on then should all verification across the form be made. What I'm unsure of is I already have a `ng-click` on that button - how do i make it do the verification first and then if successful, proceed with the actual post function. (and ideally I dont want to disable the button i.e. have it greyed out).

```
<button class="button" ng-click="home.post()">Post</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `||` inside `ng-messages`.

Answer (score 0):

May be help you.

```js
angular.module("test", []).controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.onSubmit = false;
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if(!$scope.theForm.$valid)
      $scope.onSubmit = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <form name="theForm">
      <input type="text" required name="foo" ng-model="foo" />
      <p ng-show="onSubmit && (theForm.foo.$touched || !theForm.foo.$valid)">error at foo input</p>
      
      <input type="text" required name="bar" ng-model="bar" />
      <p ng-show="onSubmit && (theForm.bar.$touched || !theForm.bar.$valid)">error at bar input</p>
      
      <button ng-click="submit()" type="button">Submit</button>  
    </form>
  </div>
```