# How to validate empty text box for mandatory field in button click in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anybody tell How to validate empty text  box for mandatory field in button click in angular js after validate i need to call web service call .Can anybody tell how to implement?

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689416/angular-validation-on-button-click-then-next-function/35693092#35693092

Comment: You can use ng-validate: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngValidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<form name="yourForm">
    <input name="name" ng-model="model.name" type="text" required />
    <div ng-messages="yourForm.name.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">Name is required!</div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="send()">Send</button>
</form>
```

And in controller js:

```
$scope.send = function () {
    if ($scope.yourForm.$valid) {

        // TODO: send model to server

    }
}
```

**Don't forget:**

Include Angular **ngMessages** module in your app.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'required' attribute to make sure they enter a value in the field

```
<input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
```

For the service call you can have a javascript method onClick , for example:

```
<button type="button" class="button" name="Search" id="searchButton" ng-click="getUserInfo()">Search</button>
```

then you do an ajax call in the Angular module

```
$scope.getUserInfo = function() 
{
    if ($scope.fetchData)
    {
        var data = {
                func: "USERINFO",
                searchUserId: $('#searchUserId').val()
        };
        $http({method:'POST',
               url:'/MYAPP/getuser',
               data: $.param(data),
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .success(function(data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.users = data;
        })
        .error(function(data,status, headers, config)  {
            alert('Error getting user infos ');
        })      
    }   
}
```

This is a quick example.  the /MYAPP/getuser maps to a REST service that returns the data in JSON format. The success(function) is what gets executed when the call is executed successfully and the data is returned. You can bind the returned data to an angular table or control for display.

.error is executed if the call fails

As for the REST services, You can write it in JAVA or C# or whatever language you like, as long as it returns JSON.